# Tkinter press buttons with enter instead of spacebar

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter you can press a highlighted button with the spacebar. How do I change that to the return key? I don't want to bind a specific function to the button, I want to change the key that presses a button if the button is highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior is implemented as bindings on the internal tk class. For the button, that class is `"Button"`.

To add the new behavior you can use `bind_class` on the class name, assuming you want this behavior for all tkinter buttons. Likewise, to remove the default behavior you can use `unbind_class` with the class name. You must do this after creating the root window.

```
import Tkinter as tk  # python 2.7
# import tkinter as tk  # python 3.x

root = tk.Tk()

# invoke the button on the return key
root.bind_class("Button", "<Key-Return>", lambda event: event.widget.invoke())

# remove the default behavior of invoking the button with the space key
root.unbind_class("Button", "<Key-space>")
```

Comment: Yup, that'll do it