# Is it possible to disable the spacebar in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a little game with Tkinter, but I'm facing a issue and I dont know how to fix it
The issue is that sometime when I press a button in the game (like the right arrow to move right for example), the function corresponding to the button is working well, but when I press spacebar just after, it calls the function again which is something I dont want.

So I'm wondering if there is any way to completly disable the space bar for tkinter ?

I've already tried 2 things:

1. Bind the spacebar to another function which is doing nothing, but when I press the spacebar it is still repeating the last button pressed
2. Unbind the space bar at the start of the code like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

game = tk.Tk()

game.unbind('<space>')
```

If you want, here is the full code of the game:
https://github.com/Nirs123/World_Of_Boats

Appreciate every feedback :)

Comment: did you bind `<Key>` as the sequence? how have you bound the other keys to call the function? you should provide a [mre] (no one is really gonna go through your entire code)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. We don't need your full code, we need a small program that behaves like your full code. The short answer is "yes, it's possible", but it will be hard for us to give a useful answer without having a minimal example to start from.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use `unbind_class()` to remove the spacebar binding for the buttons. According to information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42406164/16775594), you can use `game.unbind_class("Button", "<Key-space")`, ideally right after you crate `game` (so in line 6), and the button will no longer be able to be pressed with the spacebar.

Comment: Thanks you, this worked: `game.unbind_class("Button", "<Key-space")`

Comment: That will unbind it for _all_ buttons, but maybe that's what you want. The behavior of the spacebar is normally a feature, for when you want to traverse the UI with the keyboard instead of the mouse.

Comment: Yes it is true and this is exactly what I wanted: interact with the UI only with the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer of what I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70523827/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-spacebar-in-tkinter#comment124667095_70523827).

You can use `game.unbind_class()` to unbind a specific event for a specific type of widget. To unbind the spacebar from a button, you can use `game.unbind_class("Button", "<Key-space>")`. You can call it right after you create `game`, and all the buttons in the whole window will no longer be able to be pressed with the spacebar.